# Force figure placement inside theorem-like environment

Tags: floats, positioning

I would like a figure (including a Tikz picture) to appear inside a theorem-like environment (the point is that I need a caption for the figure).

Even using the option [H] with the float package the figure does not behave so.

Is there an easy way of accomplishing this?

Thanks

Comment: The packages [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) and [capt-of](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) offer the facilities to have captions outside of floats.

Comment: with H the figure will stay where you place it, but the only reason to use `figure` is to allow latex to move it so just using `tikzpicture` (or `\includegraphics`) directly without a figure environment is often clearer

Comment: @David Indeed, the figure does not appear where I placed it (inside the environment, i.e. just below the environment heading). On the other hand, I used `figure` to allow a caption; is it not a valid reason for using it?

Comment: as the first comment says you can add a caption anywhere if you use the capt-of package (which is just one line of code:-)

Comment: I see, if any of you wants to write this as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: but I don't see why H should not work (but the question must be a duplicate of something, probably the "when do we still need.." one in the related links on the right:-)